# How do I return the value from a callback in this promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

In my angularJS 4 app, I'm using a cordova accelerometer plugin called device motion for something.  The api has a function call getAcceleration(successCallback,errorCallback). So i created a service that looks like this

```
 @Injectable()
export class AccelerometerService {
  private acc : any;
  constructor(private winRef:WindowRef) { 
        this.acc = this.winRef.nativeWindow.plugins.navigator.accelerometer;
        this.onSuccess = this.onSuccess.bind(this);
        this.onError = this.onError.bind(this);
  }

  getAcceleration(){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{
        resolve(this.acc.getCurrentAcceleration(this.onSuccess,this.onError));      
    });
  }
  onSuccess(acceleration){
    return acceleration;    // value that I want returned to my component
  }

  onError(){
        return 'error';
  }
}
```

In my component, I do this to try to get the return value from onSuccess callback function, however the response is undefined

```
 this.accelerationService.getAcceleration().then((res) =>{
              console.log(res); // res is undefined
          })
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to resolve the promise with the result, not the return of getCurrentAcceleration.

Comment: this should be solved using observalbes

Comment: @Nickolaus Thanks. I'll look more into observables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
resolve(this.acc.getCurrentAcceleration(this.onSuccess,this.onError));
```

Do:

```
this.acc.getCurrentAcceleration(resolve, reject);
```

You don't need `this.onSuccess`.

Comment: Promises and callbacks are so confusing for me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
getAcceleration(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.acc.getCurrentAcceleration()
            .success(data => {
                resolve(<any>data);
            })
            .error(() => {
                reject('Failed to load profile');
            });
    })
}
```